# Is there a way to programmatically remove friends on Facebook?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

It sure is a pain to prune a Facebook profile. Is there any way using the Facebook API (or some other mechanism) to authenticate as a particular user and remove friends from the user's list? I have looked through the API documentation, but I'm not familiar with the ins and outs of the platform.

Answer (score 1):

I have been through the complete facebook graph api documentation on facebook while i was writing my open source .net sdk for facebook. From all that i understand, i am 99.9 % sure that this cannot be done using their api. You can create status messages, links, photos, albums, events, pages, notes etc using their api ( you need to perform simple post operations for all this ), but i have read no where that a friend can be removed using facebook api !

Answer (score 0):

No API but you can program your browser or mimick a browser. Think of QtWebKit. I doubt if you need to add so many friends and just to remove them using machine.